# How to set a selected option in Jquery Mobile using HTML?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, html-select

I have a plain **select** element, which I'm setting to the first option.

```
<select name="hersteller_typSEL" id="hersteller_typSEL" data-theme="c">
    <option value="aktiv" selected="selected">#tx_sellerlist_available_sellers#</option>
    <option value="alle">#tx_sellerlist_all_sellers#</option>
</select>
```

First time I load the page, this sometimes works...

If I then select the 2nd option and refresh the page by clicking the (**Firefox**) refresh button, I'm always getting the **2nd option as inital value**, which is driving me insane... because the selected="selected" is correct on the first option, but JQM puts the test of the 2nd option in  *ui-btn-text*

**Question**:
How can I set a selected option in JQM when the page loads afresh? (I'm not talking about going back/forth in the DOM, I'm clicking refresh in the browser (Firefox) and I'm still getting the wrong value).

Comment: Have you tried calling refresh on page load? jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html

Comment: 1.0a4.1 is a little outdated. Of course I could Jquery selectmenu('refresh'), but what I don't understand is why a full page refresh sets the option to the wrong value. A full refresh should start JQM clean, so how does the JQM ignore the selected="selected" or why does Firefox set the wrong value for JQM?

Comment: Sorry about outdated link, I'm on mobile. I've always had problems with Firefox not updating select statements properly. I've always fixed it in code.

Comment: So this is more of a Firefox issue then?

Comment: It's always been my experience, but I'm not sure if it's an "official problem"

Comment: ok. make it answer? So I can check?

Comment: Ok, but wait a little to check it in case a better answer is given ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html, you need to call `refresh` on the select element after updating it in code.

You should also do this on page load.